# Htaccess file extension in rewrite causing 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having a problem with one of my rewrite rules. I am in the process of developing an application where I want to control file access via a script. My plan is to simply pass a  rewrite rule through to my script with parameters to retrieve the appropriate file(s).

However, I am having some issues when trying to pass a file name with an extension as part of a rewrite rule. Perhaps someone can point out what i'm doing wrong.

My rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^files/(.+)/(.*)$ /index.php/files/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

What works: `http://localhost/files/12345/index`

What is causing 404 errors to be thrown: `http://localhost/files/12345/index.css`

I've been battling with this for quite some time now, it almost acts like it's trying to load the css file, not finding it, and never running the rerwite rule. I am using IntelliJ's PHP Built-in Web Server for my host environment, not sure if that has anything to do with it or not.

UPDATE:

If I go to `http://localhost/index.php/files/12345/index.css` directly the page works as expected, it does not return a 404. This rule is the only rule in my .htaccess file.

If I echo the `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"];` from the index.php I get `/files/12345/index.css` back as the value

Comment: Starting to think that the PHP Built in Web server I am using maybe just doesn't fully support .htaccess files? Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the problem was simply that PHP Built-In Web Server doesn't honor .htaccess the same as apache does. Tossed this to a full  blown apache server, and everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip existing files and directories from this rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(files/[^/]+/.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: These files / directories don't exist, and the htaccess provided does not resolve the issue anyway.

Comment: You mean `http://localhost/files/12345/index.css` doesn't exist? How about `http://localhost/index.php/files/12345/index.css`??

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://localhost/index.php/files/12345/index.css` directly in your browser?

Comment: Is there any other rule or this is the only rule (or any other .htaccess)

Comment: ok can you print `echo $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"];` from your `index.php` and see what it prints for `http://localhost/files/12345/index.css` URL?